# setTimeout on Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am using a simple `setTimeOut()` to prevent blocking of the `UI` like this:

```
setTimeout(function () {
  somefunction(m);
}, 0);
```

This works fine in `IE` and other browsers.  But the `UI` is still blocked in mobile browsers such as chrome mobile and galaxy sIII built-in webkit browser. Any ideas why?

Comment: I guess it depends on what's in someFunction...

Comment: `setTimeout` passing `0` as the time argument is the same as only having `somefunction(m);` make your `somefunction(m);` asynchronous and you will be ok.

Comment: Set delay to 100 at least. Mobile browsers has internal delay.

Answer (score 2):

Due to the nature of mobile browsers which have a built-in delay, you always need to set delay higher than zero.

```
setTimeout(function () {
  somefunction(m);
}, 10);
```

**Edit:** As @Doorknob mentioned in his comment, 10ms would be fine in order not cause more delay when setting value higher than 100ms.

Comment: Meh, anything ten or higher would be fine. no need to wait a tenth of a second - repeatedly doing that could cause noticeable delays

Comment: @Omar Would you clarify? I would think a "built in delay" would make it so that a delay of 0ms would work fine, since the browser will add its own delay?

Answer (score 0):

Timeout of 0 is not helping, timeout is in milliseconds.  Also would be able to help whats your callback function trying to do, if your callback function is holding on to the dom , after timeout interval also you would experience the same.